# Как вручную создать файл gmdb для работы с Gmap.NET?

Tags: c#, openstreetmap, gmap.net

Как создать файл cache.gmdb с данными всей страны, с разными уровнями масштабирования. Для возможности использования библиотеки Gmap.Net.
Возможно ли конвертация данных из geofabric в gmdb или PostgreSQL?
P.S. Основной код написан с помощью Gmap.Net а для поддержки offline хочу брать данные из gmdb чтобы не переписывать всю структуру кода

Comment: gmdb и PostgreSQL это базы данных. Какая структура вам нужна? Какие данные нужны? Это уже конкретно от вашей программы зависит.

Comment: в PostgreSQL  хранятся данные полученные из файла osm.pbf но как сделать запрос на добавление данных в  gmdb от PostgreSQL. Данные были добавлены с помощью этого метода http://openstreetmapserverwindows.blogspot.com/2015/11/osmopenstreetmap-tile-server.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для тех, кто так же, как и мне нужно было сделать offline, карты использую Gmap,  на официальном репозитории Gmap https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps, есть готовый код, для создания кеша выделенного участка карты в разных масштабах.